# How to calculate $\int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^2-1\right)^n \left(x\right)\right)^2dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I'm trying to calculate 
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \left( \frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^2-1\right)^n \left(x\right)\right)^2dx$$
I found that this question is about to Legendre polynomials and Rodrigues' formula. 
However, I still couldn't get an answer for this question. How to make this computation in a good way?

Comment: You can perform integration by parts $n$ times. All the intermediate boundary terms vanish and you will end up with a very neat integral.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you so much. I will try again.

Comment: In doing so, it is worth noticing that $ \frac{d^k}{dx^k} (x^2 - 1)^n$ is divisible by $(x^2 - 1)^{n-k}$ for any $k = 0, \cdots, n$. (This is easily proved by the mathematical induction.) This can be used to show that the boundary terms appearing from integration by parts vanish.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks again for your kind consideration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you search for the properties of Legendre's Polynomials you will get the answer to your question eventhough looks complicated at first sight!

A good reference is - [here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahdrb/MATHM242/OutlineCD2.pdf),check the properties there.

$\int_{-1}^{1} (P_{n})^2 dx = \frac{2}{2n + 1}$ where $P_{n}(x)$ is the Legendre Polynomial $\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(x^2-1\right)^n \left(x\right)$

Hope this illustrates!

Comment: You are welcome! also I see you are new to this site,I hope you would gain much here :) also you should upvote , mark as accepted to the answer you are satisfied with!@KDRL